# Compare multiple sets of columns to produce boolean result column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Using Pandas, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
col_a   col_b    col_a1    col_b1
Larry   Larry     Peter     Peter
Lee     Lee      Jeremy    Ilia
```

I want to compare `col_a` to `col_b`, and `col_a1` to `col_b1`.  If both pairs match, indicate it in a new column (`flag`):

```
col_a   col_b    col_a1    col_b1   flag
Larry   Larry     Peter     Peter   True
Lee     Lee      Jeremy    Ilia     False
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.eval`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col_a":["Larry","Lee"],
    "col_b":["Larry","Lee"],
    "col_a1":["Peter","Jeremy"],
    "col_b1":["Peter","Ilia"]
    })

print df
df["flag"] = df.eval("col_a==col_b and col_a1==col_b1")    
print df
```

Output:

```
   col_a  col_a1  col_b col_b1
0  Larry   Peter  Larry  Peter
1    Lee  Jeremy    Lee   Ilia

   col_a  col_a1  col_b col_b1   flag
0  Larry   Peter  Larry  Peter   True
1    Lee  Jeremy    Lee   Ilia  False
```

If it happens that the columns to be compared are stored in two lists like `a_cols` and `b_cols` you can do something like:

```
a_cols = ["col_a","col_a1"]
b_cols = ["col_b","col_b1"]
df["flag"] = df.eval(" and ".join("%s==%s" % pair for pair in zip(a_cols,b_cols)))   
print df
```

Output:

```
   col_a  col_a1  col_b col_b1   flag
0  Larry   Peter  Larry  Peter   True
1    Lee  Jeremy    Lee   Ilia  False
```

Comment: it's looks like col_a, col_b are hard code int to df.eval, do we have one way to loop the columns by pairs? how we can do that?

Comment: @LarryWoo what exactly do you want to do? Please give more details or maybe ask another question, I will try to help you anyway ;)

Comment: for example, we don't know exactly columns numbers in Dataframe, it's dynamic, I would read the by function ,columns get all the columns and store in List, then trying to compare data by pairs, how I can loop the List and make df.eval() to work?

Comment: @LarryWoo  OK, let me see if I'm understanding you, what you say is that the columns to be compared are dynamically generated? Well if that's the case you can construct the `eval` string, I will put an example on my answer ;)

Comment: @LarryWoo I've updated my answer, hope it helps, if you need help understanding the string operations don be afraid to ask. If you found my answer useful please upvote or mark as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the apply function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':('A','B'), 'col_b':('A','B'), 'col_a1':('C','D'),'col_b1':('C','E')})

df = df[['col_a','col_b','col_a1','col_b1']]

df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: ('True' if x['col_a']== x['col_b'] and x['col_a1']==x['col_b1'] else 'False'),axis=1)

print df
```

Comment: `'col_a1'('C','D')` should be `'col_a1':('C','D')` and this method restricts it two-column comparison, OP's input can have multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  My code looks fine so I must have copied it over and accidentally deleted that colon.

Answer (score 0):

I find the following code to be much simpler to read through. 
You just have to compare two columns at a time and `and` both the results to get the `flag` column:

In one line:

```
In [18]: tf['flag'] = (tf['col_a'] == tf['col_b']) & (tf['col_a1'] == tf['col_b1'])

In [19]: tf
Out[19]: 
   col_a  col_b  col_a1 col_b1   flag
0  Larry  Larry   Peter  Peter   True
1    Lee    Lee  Jeremy   Ilia  False
```